# Is new optimization options In GCC real?

Tags: gcc

I badly needed a smaller output file and replaced the -O3 with -Os. Now, I see output file is considerably smaller and I do not notice performance degradation. Is replacing -O3 with -Os Ok?.  Or, I am just lucky my code is working .. I suppose -Os still do some speed an other optimizations ....

Comment: Yes, often there is no performance loss if you replace `-O3` with `-Os`. It my even run faster with `-Os`. If you read the documentation, `-Os` mostly does what `-O2` except those optimizations that would increase the executable size significantly. You may want to check out [Reducing Executable Size](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size#GCC_Specific).